# How do you animate menu with framer motion on-click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations, framer-motion

(Using React obviously + Gatsby)
I have a hamburger button that gonna open a nav-menu in my website.
I wanted to know how to make the menu open with an animation using Framer Motion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use this method that is given in the examples section of the framer motion documentation.

[Framer Motion API Documentation](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/examples/)

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion"

const variants = {
  open: { opacity: 1, x: 0 },
  closed: { opacity: 0, x: "-100%" },
}

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <motion.nav
      animate={isOpen ? "open" : "closed"}
      variants={variants}
    >
      'Menu Content'
    </motion.nav>
  )
}
```